# FCM delivery reports vs FCM export data to bigquery

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to investigate why delivery rate of my app notifications is so low.

I have access to FCM delivery reports. I wanted to ask if the option of "FCM export data to bigquery" offers anything substantial that is not covered by FCM delivery reports.

How can I find the root cause of low delivery rate? FCM delivery rate is only telling me that the rate is low, but not the cause.